# Placing dots in the numbers of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, gsub

I am using R and this is how my data looks like,

```
 a <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,2,3),icd9=c("0781","00840","8660","7100","25011"))
```

I want to place a dot after the 3rd digit in both four digits and five-digit numbers in second column. I am using `gsub` in R but not getting desired output. My desired data frame is:

```
id   icd9
1    078.1
2    008.40
2    866.0
2    710.0
3    250.11
```

I am trying

```
gsub('([0-9])', '\\1\\2\\3.\\4', a$icd9)
```

But I am getting

```
[1] "0.7.8.1."   "0.0.8.4.0." "8.6.6.0."   "7.1.0.0."   "2.5.0.1.1."
```

Thanks, guys in advance :)

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: Hi Elin, I am using gsub and I am new to regular expressions, this is how I am trying gsub('([0-9])', '\\1\\2\\3.\\4', a$icd9). But I am getting,  "0.7.8.1."   "0.0.8.4.0." "8.6.6.0."   "7.1.0.0."   "2.5.0.1.1.   I only need dot after 3rd digit

Comment: try `sub('(?<=.{3})', '.', a$icd9, perl = TRUE)` or `sub('(.{3})(.*)', '\\1.\\2', a$icd9)`

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it worked. thanks. I have posted another question if possible for you to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  mutate(num = as.numeric(paste0(substr(icd9,1,3),".",substr(icd9,4,nchar(icd9)))))

  id  icd9    num
1  1  0781  78.10
2  2 00840   8.40
3  2  8660 866.00
4  2  7100 710.00
5  3 25011 250.11
```

Comment: Actually, I need the exact output as mentioned in my question. I am converting ICD9 codes to phecodes. Based on the output of your code, 78.10 is not a valid icd code and I need exactly 078.1 , 008.40 , 866.0, 710.0, 250.11. Thanks for your prompt response and help

Comment: This is working for me,                                                                                        library(dplyr)
a %>% 
mutate(num = (paste0(substr(icd9,1,3),".",substr(icd9,4,nchar(icd9)))))                                               thanks guys for your quick responses :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
sub('^(\\d{3})(\\d)', '\\1.\\2', a$icd9)
# => [1] "078.1"  "008.40" "866.0"  "710.0"  "250.11"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/rLuZIr) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hXuV1m/1). *Details*:

- `sub` is used since there is only one search and replace operation on each string
- `^(\d{3})(\d)` matches the first three digits (`^` is start of string and `\d{3}` is three digits) into Group 1  (due to `(...)`) and the next digit is captured into Group 2
- The replacement is Group 1 + `.` + Group 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to map ICD9 codes to phecodes, please include that info in your question. This approach may be useful to you:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#remotes::install_github("PheWAS/PheWAS")
library(PheWAS)
#> Loading required package: parallel
#install.packages("fuzzyjoin")
library(fuzzyjoin)

a <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,2,3),icd9=c("0781","00840","8660","7100","25011"))

ci_str_detect <- function(x, y) {
  str_detect(y, pattern = sub('(?<=.{3})', '.', x, perl = TRUE))
}

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(a, phecode_map, by = c("icd9" = "code"), match_fun = ci_str_detect)
#>   id  icd9 vocabulary_id   code phecode
#> 1  1  0781        ICD9CM  078.1     078
#> 2  1  0781        ICD9CM 078.10     078
#> 3  1  0781        ICD9CM 078.11     078
#> 4  1  0781        ICD9CM 078.12     078
#> 5  1  0781        ICD9CM 078.19     078
#> 6  2 00840          <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
#> 7  2  8660        ICD9CM E866.0     984
#> 8  2  7100        ICD9CM  710.0  695.42
#> 9  3 25011        ICD9CM 250.11  250.11
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

"008.40" doesn't appear to be a valid ICD9 code. "008.41" is valid though, so if you use that instead you don't get the "NA" values in line 6.

Comment: Thanks and it's very useful. Actually, I am dealing with UKBB data. In UKBB all the ICD9 codes are saved in four and five digit formats without dot in between them. It's really difficult to specify the correct pattern in order to use the 'PHEWAS' package. What I am doing, is placing dot after 3 digits in all 4 and 5 digits ICD 9 codes. I am not really sure if it's the correct strategy. At the end, I am getting very less number of diabetes patients with a Phecode 250.1. It would be great and save my time if you have any further suggestions @jared_mamrot

Comment: I was under the impression that other groups have solved this problem - e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6911227/ - but this isn't my area of expertise. This type of question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/. There is a similar question there (https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/icd10-code-list) where they suggest this package: https://github.com/jackwasey/icd (definitely worth a look)